# Symfony2: How to make username of FOSUserBundle user unique

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have my own `User` Class, which inherits `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User`. Additionally I wrote my own registration routine. Now I have the problem that the form does not make sure that the username is unique. I always get:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'myusername' for key 'UNIQ_2DA1797792FC23A8'

I tried adding the `@UniqueEntity("email")` annotation as stated in the documentation[1](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html), but without any effect.

Someone knows what might be wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The constraint exists in the FOS bundle already. You probably need to set the `validation_groups` option on your form to `array('Registration')`.

Comment: This does not have any effect :/ any more ideas?

Comment: However, here is the link to the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#book-forms-validation-groups

Comment: posted an issue on github. great support crew there. thanks so much to @stof for pointing out that I did not actually validate the user object but just the form data. More info: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/480

Answer (score 14):

If you're using the fos_user bundle, you can simply use the UniqueEntity constraint: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html.

To implement it, just make sure your User class constains the proper use statements, and then the annotations, like so (assuming you're using annotations):

```
<?php
// ...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks Vraxoin! During my unit tests I was getting an ugly DB level violation (SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation) when I tried to register a username that already existed... I've search high and low and found many complicated answers (most didn't really seem like they would address the issue). On a whim, I gave this a shot (only 4 lines to copy and paste right?) and now my non-unique registration attempts are now handled gracefully (FOSUB now redirects the user to the registration form again rather than the DB exception). Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on the `validation.yml` with your user entity validation:

```
constraints:    
    - FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Unique:
        property: usernameCanonical
        message:  'This username already exists. Please choose another one.'
```