# FOS UserManager create user catch duplicate login

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $newUser = $userManager->createUser();
        $newUser->setUsername($form["username"]->getData());
        $newUser->setPlainPassword($form["password"]->getData());
        $newUser->setEmail($form["email"]->getData());
        if($form["isadmin"]->getData() == TRUE){
            $newUser->addRole("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN");
        }
        $newUser->setEnabled($form["enabled"]->getData());

        try {

            $userManager->updateUser($newUser);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'error', 'Wystąpił błąd przy udodawaniu użytkownika!'
            );
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('backend_users_list'));

        }
```

Some part from controller, but if username is duplicated, i dont have redirect.

> QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'admin' for key 'UNIQ_957A647992FC23A8'

I gave Unique error from mysql only, how to catch a user duplicate exception from UserManager?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2: How to make username of FOSUserBundle user unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744070/symfony2-how-to-make-username-of-fosuserbundle-user-unique)

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16304072/1188035)